# What protocols are used by Usenet? How easily can it be detected by the ISP?

Tags: networking, ip, usenet

I am trying to figure out if Usenet can be detected by the ISP?

My ISP has put me behind a NAT and probably is monitoring each packet. I want to know if I can usenet. My usenet client has the option to use SSL to fetch articles. So is it un detectable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia (the first place I looked), Usenet uses the Network News Transfer Protocol. As for your ISP monitoring packets, that sounds absurd. Unless you have a very small, invasive ISP, there is no reason for them to do that. I don't see why they would care about Usenet in particular. But SSL will not make the connection undetectable, it will only hide the data being transferred across the connection. If that's a problem, you might want to try Tor.

[torproject.org](https://www.torproject.org/)